# How to get only specific value in REST API JSON response?

Tags: flutter, api, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using REST API to get data from my Learndash courses. I need a list of ID, title, and feature images. I used `..` to get the lists of IDs and titles. But when I use `_embed` I also get IDs from `wp:featuredmedia`. So I want just `source_link` from `wp:featuredmedia`

I tried `_fields` parameter and also _embedded. Nothing is working

My question is, How to get only the id, title, and featuredmedia link from REST API call?

Comment: Please share response sample

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mdrashedbinkuddus/23239e9058211a3940fec42d2419a24e

Comment: You can try this way :    var data = jsonDecode(res.body);
  
      data[0]['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia'][0]['source_url']        Where res.body is your jsonresponse